# SQL Server Login failed for user Jboss AS7

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, jboss7.x

I am attempting to set up multiple datasources in my standalone.xml file. I have a connection to DB2 up and working fine. I am having trouble getting the SQL Server connection to work. 
From standalone.xml:

```
        <datasource jndi-name="java:/jdbc/syteline" pool-name="SYTELINEMSSDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true" spy="true">
            <connection-url>jdbc:sqlserver://SLSQL:1433;databaseName=npsl_pilot_app;</connection-url>
            <driver-class>com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</driver-class>
            <driver>sqljdbc4.jar</driver>
            <pool>
                <min-pool-size>5</min-pool-size>
                <max-pool-size>10</max-pool-size>
                <prefill>true</prefill>
                <use-strict-min>false</use-strict-min>
            </pool>
            <security>
                <user-name>myUser</user-name>
                <password>myPass</password>
            </security>
            <timeout>
                <idle-timeout-minutes>15</idle-timeout-minutes>
            </timeout>
        </datasource>
```

I have the sqljdbc4.jar deployed in my standalone\deployments directory and it is deploying. I have tested the connection URL and credentials by copy/pasting it into my application and creating a JDBC connection within my code. That connection works properly. Setting the connection up as a datasource in standalone.xml gives me the following:

```
15:20:00,326 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-15) JBAS010400: Bound data source [java:/jdbc/syteline]
15:20:00,684 WARN  [org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.strategy.OnePool] (JCA PoolFiller) IJ000610: Unable to fill pool: javax.resource.ResourceException: Could not create connection
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.getLocalManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:277)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.createManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:235)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.mcp.SemaphoreArrayListManagedConnectionPool.createConnectionEventListener(SemaphoreArrayListManagedConnectionPool.java:758) [ironjacamar-core-impl-1.0.7.Final.jar:1.0.7.Final]
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.mcp.SemaphoreArrayListManagedConnectionPool.fillToMin(SemaphoreArrayListManagedConnectionPool.java:703) [ironjacamar-core-impl-1.0.7.Final.jar:1.0.7.Final]
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.mcp.PoolFiller.run(PoolFiller.java:97) [ironjacamar-core-impl-1.0.7.Final.jar:1.0.7.Final]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [rt.jar:1.6.0_23]
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Login failed for user 'dna'. ClientConnectionId:4e4e0e7f-3e23-4a13-9c49-37e33aeb4613
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:216)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSTokenHandler.onEOF(tdsparser.java:254)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSParser.parse(tdsparser.java:84)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.sendLogon(SQLServerConnection.java:2908)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.logon(SQLServerConnection.java:2234)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.access$000(SQLServerConnection.java:41)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection$LogonCommand.doExecute(SQLServerConnection.java:2220)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:5696)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:1715)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:1326)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:991)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:827)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:1012)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.getLocalManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:249)
    ... 5 more

15:20:01,385 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-14) Class Path entry jcifs.jar in "/C:/jbossdir/jboss7/standalone/deployments/speed2.war/WEB-INF/lib/jtds-1.2.5.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
```

I have not been able to figure out the Login Failed message.

Comment: I remember SQLServer JDBC driver had some problems with certain builds of JDK. Downgrading JDK from 1.6.0_31 to 1.6.0_29 or so helped me :)

Comment: I tried upgrading java to 1.7.0_03-b05. Still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as a followup, I gave up on the Microsoft driver and used JTDS instead. Works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Is the JBoss server on the same computer as the test application that can connect properly?

Comment: Yes, it is the same computer. I hard coded the jdbc connection into my application then deployed it to the standalone directory. So the above failure happens when JBoss starts up but I am still able to make the direct connection and pull data from code within the same JBoss container.